# AngularJs: how to show a value twice

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add a value to HTML using Angular, but I can't figure out why I cannot see the intended result. Here is my code:

```
<div class="panel style5" ng-repeat="profile in profiles">
    <dd class="display-counter" data-value="{{profile.views_count}}">{{profile.views_count}}</dd>
</div>
```

Here is the HTML output:

```
<dd data-value="16" class="display-counter">NaN</dd>
```

I am having a difficult time understanding why 16 is not shown on both places. Do I need to assign this value to another variable?

Comment: Where is profile stored?

Comment: AR7 - I have added more code to it.. it is coming from an array

Comment: Can you post the controller code please? There is no reason to why that shouldnt work. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/k8jcumvL/

Comment: RSquared.. you are right... there was no Angular-related reason. Comes to find out, there is a jQuery plugin I am running on the site, that was making that is somehow clearing `profile.views_account`. As soon as I remove the class "display-counter" the issue goes away. I am just gonna stop using it....

Comment: Thanks you all for the help